# Confusion regarding android API levels?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-tools, build.gradle

I was following through a Udacity course on android , and these terms seem to confuse me 
(i use android studio 1.x latest version)
In my build.gradle i have these

```
   compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
......
    minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

....

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
```

**My assumption**
If I leave the app theme as default that is  in my  manifest file,i set it to use `app:theme` and in styles.xml it is by default

```
appcompat.light.darkaction bar
```

I figured out the `appcompat` theme means ,it changes to use the theme for the version of the target SDK irrespective of the device OS version

when i chose API 21 ,it looked like a material app
when i chose API 20, it looked like a kitkat app
(both on my device which runs ICS)

so target SDK is contolling the look and feel of my app irrespective of device OS,
it defines what highest version of android the device can support , right?and by default the look and feel change to the latest or the target API look and feel whilst using app:compat theme still enabling it to run on lower sdks ,,as low as API 10

and minsdk is the minumum supported ,

*am i right till here?*

Now what confuses me is

what's compile SDK , should it always be the latest available ?

*Example : material didnt show app icon in action bar icon , i didn't like it , and switched to API 20
to follow with the MOOC videos*

but should i leave compile sdk as 21 , wont that make the app look like material , cause i'm confused as it didnt?

And a final question ,
I want to test the app on devices running gingerbread, i don't have any,
can you suggest some typical AVD config for gingerbread devices(cause i know a lotta people still use it in developing nation),
what ram,screen size and pixel density should i use that fits a typical gingerbread device?

Answer (score 4):

> so target SDK is controlling the look and feel of my app irrespective of device OS,

Yes. (among other things)

> it defines what highest version of android the device can support , right?

No ! The target SDK indicates the SDK you use to test your app. You can use a target SDK 20 and run your  app on a device with API 21 installed : it will use the KitKat l&f (i.e level 20).

How is it possible ? When an app targeting API 20 is running on a device with API 21 : the system will automatically enable some *backward compatibility hook* so that your app behaves just like it behave on older versions (i.e. targetVersion) of the OS.

The maximum sdk supported is the maxSdk attribute (rarely used and not recommended). If you specify a maxSdk 20 : you **won't be able to install** your app on a device running SDK 21+

The compile SDK level is the version of the sdk you use to compile your app. If you choose the latest one : the users of the latest android version will benefit of code that is optimized for them. It will allow you to use the latest features of the sdk... but be careful when you write code using new apis since it will crash on older devices.(see here under)

The minimum sdk version may be lower than the compile sdk. In your example you are declaring that your code can be executed on API level 10, but compiled with api level 21... that's OK but you MUST ensure that every calls to API that don't exist in API-10 won't be executed on a device running API-10.

Let's illustrate this tricky point. Assume : compileSdk = 20 ; targetSdk = 20 and minSdk = 10

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
    apiCallToSomethingAvailableOnlySinceApi13();
}else {
    //put here some alternative code to perform something similar 
    //(but probably degraded) feature
    //on device running API 10, 11 or 12
    //device with api 9 or lower are exclude anyway (because minSdk is 10)
}
```

To summarize :

**minSDK** : it is possible to install the app on a device with at least this level and the developer wrote defensive code to ensure that all calls to api more recent than minSdk won't be executed on device running the minSdk version.

**targetSDK** : the app was tested on this level and more recent devices must enable *backward compatibility hook* so that the app still behave as if it was running on this level even on more recent devices.

**compileSDK** : the code is optimized to run on this level. (usually safe to put it the same as targetSDK)

**maxSDK** : you cannot install the app on a device running higher API (not recommended and most of the time not useful).

Comment: @DroidIcs  sorry I don't see the problem. Can you be more precise ?

Comment: Check your explanation for minsdk